# Best techniques to prepare image-based web design for SEO - noscript?

Tags: html, image, seo, alt, noscript

Okay, so I know that this is really frowned upon, and this is something that I don't typically do. In fact, I've never launched a website like this one. But there doesn't seem to be much of an alternative.

I am working with a web design with a client that is essentially just a full-page slider. The original design looks like it could've been ported to Flash. I plan on using jQuery so at least it isn't plugin-dependent, but the content text is intricately designed and incorporated into the slide images.

From what I'm seeing, the only text that I can actually place onto the page without embedding in an image is the navigation and maybe part of the site header.

There is a lot of content in the slide images -- too much for putting in an alt="" attribute on the <img /> tag. I know that the longdesc="" attribute is deprecated from HTML5 and isn't really supported well anyway, so that's out. I thought of duplicating the text from the image and placing it in a hidden <div></div> tag, or in a <noscript></noscript> tag, or offsetting it so it's invisible, and other methods of hiding content for dynamic, JavaScript-based sites. However, I am also aware that search engine developers like Google frown on that sort of thing and it might harm my SEO rankings.

The <noscript></noscript> element would be a good solution, but from my understanding you can only implement it legitimately if the content of the element duplicates content that exists elsewhere in the document and is dynamically controlled. Maybe I misinterpreted that?

Are there any other solutions you can think of?

Comment: Another idea I thought of is to place the image in a div with text below it, and then set an explicit height for the div and add overflow: hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `object` element

You could use `object` instead of `img`. The content of the [`object` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-object-element) will be used as fallback (resp. as alternative for screen reader users or search engine bots):

```
<object data="your-image.png" type="image/png">
  <!-- the alternative/fallback content -->
</object>
```

#### `longdesc` attribute

Or you could use the `longdesc` attribute for the `img` element, which is defined in a separate specificiation: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-longdesc/ (Working Draft):

> This specification defines a `longdesc` attribute to link extended descriptions with images in HTML5-based content.

#### `meta`-`description`

In addition you could include the text (or the beginning resp. a summary of it) in the [`description`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#meta-description)-[`meta` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element):

```
<meta name="description" content"…">
```

But this would only work if you have separate URLs for each image (which could be accomplished with the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries))

Comment: Great suggestions! The <object> element may make the most sense, since I heard longdesc isn't widely supported and I'm worried crawlers wouldn't follow it. I'm wondering, though, if <object data="a png file"> is cross-browser, though?

Comment: @MMiller: I don’t know details about `object` support, whether in (older) browsers or search engines. However, the `object` element is pretty "old", so I guess/hope most user-agents should handle it fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a *place-holder* `div`, that contains the text-based content. Than create a JavaScript function (onload) to replace the `innerHTML` property of the *place-holder* with the image!

Comment: From my understanding, though, Googlebot and other crawlers are starting to read JavaScript now. Doesn't this mean that Google will replace my text-based content with an image and then read NO content?

Comment: If you place the text in a noscript element, it will get less attention and weight. But the site's behaviour is the same, because the image is only shown when JavaScript is enabled. If somebody at Google will review your site, they don't get you banned, because you don't manipulate the data, just make it readable to spiders.